# mathematic operation 2 table in sql

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, vb.net-2010

**With SQL database in visual studio 2012.**

But i don't know how to make them have an automatic math operation. the case:
There is 3 table in datagridview:

1. salary
2. salary_Overtime
3. salary_cuts
4. Total

Total = (salary + salary_overtime) - salary_cuts

I already write some coding here, but its doesn't have impact when i save a new data. i ask my friend, he said you should add new trigger.

==Salary== ==Salary_Overtime== ==Salary_Cuts== ==Total==

==5000== ==2000== ==1000== ==6000==

Comment: Please add your relevant columns, example data, expected output and the query you are stuck with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [**Computed Column**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188300.aspx) in SQL Server to do what you're trying to do.

**Specify Computed Columns in a Table:**

> A computed column is a virtual column that is not physically stored in
>   the table, unless the column is marked PERSISTED. A computed column
>   expression can use data from other columns to calculate a value for
>   the column to which it belongs. You can specify an expression for a
>   computed column in in SQL Server 2016 by using SQL Server Management
>   Studio or Transact-SQL.

So an example is below. Note the `Total` column contains the calculation so when you query the table it will calculate the value for you:

```
CREATE TABLE #Salary
    (
      salary INT ,
      salary_overtime INT ,
      salary_cuts INT ,
      Total AS ( salary + salary_overtime ) - salary_cuts
    );

-- Insert values into the table.
INSERT  INTO #Salary
        ( salary ,
          salary_overtime ,
          salary_cuts
        )
VALUES  ( 5000 ,
          2000 ,
          1000 
        )

SELECT  *
FROM    #Salary

-- Produces:
--salary    salary_overtime salary_cuts Total
--5000      2000            1000        6000

-- After an UPDATE:
UPDATE  #Salary
SET     salary_cuts = 2000

SELECT  *
FROM    #Salary

-- Produces:
-- salary   salary_overtime salary_cuts Total
-- 5000     2000            2000        5000

DROP TABLE #Salary
```